# Testing Snackbar show with Espresso

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-testing, android-espresso, android-snackbar

Is there a way to test using Espresso that the snackbar shows up with the right text?

I have a simple call to create a snackbar

```
Snackbar.make(mView, "My text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have tried this without luck

```
onView(withText("My text")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This worked for me, please try.

```
onView(allOf(withId(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text), withText("My text")))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

If you use AndroidX, please use the following:

```
onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text))
        .check(matches(withText(R.string.whatever_is_your_text)))
```

Comment: What do you do when espresso do the check at the time snackbar's `Y` position is `0.0`? `isDisplayed` throws exception.

Comment: make sure you do don't add this assert when y position is 0.0, this means either your snackbar is done showing or yet to show. you might need to adjust the test to make sure you either wait until its shown or check a bit earlier depends on your scenario

Comment: @ksarmalkar How should we wait for this, then?

Comment: One way would be to add your own matcher that polls every few millis with a max timeout so that it does not run indefinitely. pretty sure there might be lots of other ways to handle this. few come to mind, add a listener for snackbar dismiss and fail in case the dismiss is never invoked indicating the snackbar was never shown.

Comment: I get `NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.my.package.debug:id/snackbar_text` with this. Any ideas?

Comment: your snackbar is probably hiding before this is asserted, maybe try adding more delay to hiding snackbar and see if it works

Comment: @ksarmalkar , How did you find this : `onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text))
        .check(matches(withText(R.string.whatever_is_your_text)))`

Answer (score 16):

An alternative

```java
private void checkSnackBarDisplayedByMessage(@StringRes int message) {
    onView(withText(message))
            .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
}
```

Comment: Perfect, i think can be used for every generic text

Comment: Use withEffectiveVisibility instead of isDisplayed so it doesn't matter whether it is actually displayed in the current screen.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the previous answers but I thought this would be better.

```
@Test
public void onFabClick_shouldDisplaySnackbar() throws Exception {
  onView(withId(R.id.fab)).perform(click());

  // Compare with the text message of snackbar
  onView(withText(R.string.snackbar_message))
      .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

Comment: where do we import 'withText' from?

Comment: @Phlip import like this: import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText