# Snackbar and Espresso failing sometimes

Tags: android, android-espresso

As the title says, it fails some times, some others it success.

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.

Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131492981, res-name=snackbar_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=444, height=71, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=18.0, y=0.0, text=Network Error, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

The first line of stack trace suggest espresso is unable to see the Snackbar on screen. But the second line states it is in fact seeing a Snackbar with `visibility=VISIBLE` and `text=Network Error` which is correct.

I'm confused, what's going on?

This is my test code:

```
activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
onView(withText("Network Error")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

PS: it mostly fails when I run the whole test suit; but sometimes it also fails when I just run this test alone. Some other times it passes green, but there isn't any pattern, seems random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late! But I hope that it is helpful for others:

[Testing Snackbar show with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111882/testing-snackbar-show-with-espresso/33245290)

```
private void checkSnackBarDisplayedByMessage(@StringRes int message) {
    onView(withText(message))
        .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(
            ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE
    )));
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I'm so glad there's a solution to this that doesn't require giving up on UI tests.

Comment: Actually I just tried this, too, and I got the same issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar issue. I was able to solve it by:

1. Disabeling animations as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html#setup).
2. I was displaying the SnackBar after I fetched data from server so I also had to wait until the data was fetched. I managed to solve it with [IdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820189/2465895) anwser.

Then I was able to successfully check the SnackBar.

I hope my points will help.